# Vsix template is not working and get error, how to get logs?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, templates, vsix, vsixmanifest

I have a vsix with multiple templates, in debug mode i can run vsix and everythings is working fine. I have 2 vs installed. v17.x and v18 preview 1.
But when i install my vsix, i can use it in v18 but in vs v17.x. i get error when i choose my template.
If i remove vsix and repair vs v17.x i can install vsix and everything is working fine but if i update vsix again it does not work

How i can debug it when i am not in vs? Is there any way to get logs?

Comment: Have the source.extension.vsixmanifest set the targets? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/migration/update-visual-studio-extension?view=vs-2022#extensions-without-running-code